# How to replace the character I want in a line

Tags: vim

```
1 aaa bbb aaa
2 aaa ccccccccc aaa
3 aaa xx aaa
```

How to replace the **second** aaa to yyy for each line

```
1 aaa bbb yyy
2 aaa ccccccccc yyy
3 aaa xx yyy
```

Answer (score 2):

Issuing the following command will solve your problem.

```
  :%s/\(aaa.\{-}\)aaa/\1yyy/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be with `\zs` and `\ze`, which mark the beginning and end of a match in a pattern. So you could do:

```
:%s/aaa.*\zsaaa\ze/yyy
```

In other words, find "aaa" followed by anything and then another "aaa", and replace that with "yyy".

If you have three "aaa"s on a line, this won't work, though, and you should use `\{-}` instead of `*`. (See `:h non-greedy`)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

`:%s/aaa.*\zsaaa/yyy`

Without using \ze command.